# Is it possible to get fresh Google Slides presentation data in AppsScript?

Tags: google-apps-script, concurrency, locking, simultaneous, google-slides

It seems that if one uses `SlidesApp.getActivePresentation()` in AppsScript, the result of the function is not fresh but rather something that was already prepared beforehand.

**Scenario**

Imagine you have two users performing the following function in AppsScript simultaneously:

```
function updateSlideText(slideId) {
  // Request exclusive write access to the document
  var lock = LockService.getDocumentLock();
  lock.waitLock(15000);

  // Perform changes
  var presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var textBox = presentation.getSlideById(MY_SLIDE_ID).getPageElementById(MY_TEXTBOX_ID);
  textBox.asShape().getText().setText('My text');

  // Save and release lock
  presentation.saveAndClose();
  lock.releaseLock();
}
```

If this function is called twice at the same time, the resulting slide contains text "My textMy text".[image: Example outpu]

When I add `Utilities.sleep(10000)` just before the lock release, it delays the 2nd execution by 10s but after those 10s I still end up with the same result. On the other hand, if I actually delay **calling** the function 10s, the output is fine.

From this I conclude that it does not matter if I call `saveAndClose` and use locks. Once the function is called, it will always have stale data. Is there a way around this? Is it not possible to request that fresh data will be loaded after the lock is aquired?

**More details**

Some more pseudo-code to better illustrate the problem use-case:

```
// The addon frontend
websocket.onMessage((message) => {
  if (message.type === 'pollUpdate') {
    const slideWithPoll = store.getState().slides.find(
      slide => slide.pollId === message.pollId
    );

    if (slideWithPoll.title !== message.poll.title) {
      google.script.run.updateSlideText(slideWithPoll.id, message.poll.title);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: May I ask you - if two users run the function simulateously - how do the y do it? Is the function bound to a trigger, a function in the custom menu, run directly from the script editor?

Comment: It is triggered by our own server. Both users have our addon open and this addon receives messages via websocket. In response, the addon is supposed to update the content of the slide. This way we synchronize parts of the Google Slides presentation data with the data we have on our own end.

In this case, both users receive the same message (which is ok) and they both want to perform the same update. There are other ways we could solve this but none of them is very elegant. :/

Comment: This problem is interesting, since in the snippet above you are not adding additional text, but reset to whatever the textBox contained before to 'My text', so it is not really relevant either you have old or fresh data. Maybe your real code has some more dependencies you did not mention? In any case, does adding `Utilities.sleep(10000) ` at the beginning of the function solve the problem? Btw., adding `saveAndClose()` at the end of a function is not necessary because Google does it anyway.

Comment: Yes, the behavior is really strange, I'm guessing it is just a symptom of how that API works internally. I'll try moving the sleep to the beginning, though I'm not sure why it would help. With that explicit `saveAndClose()` I wanted to ensure that the 2nd client doesn't enter the editing part of the code until the changes from the 1st client are saved (it's **before** the `releaseLock()`).

Comment: What do you mean by *It is triggered by our own server.*? Could you go step by step flow from user interaction?

Comment: @davido Can I ask you about `other ways we could solve this` of `There are other ways we could solve this but none of them is very elegant.`?

Comment: @TheMaster, we have a poll which you can update via another web interface. The Slides addon should reflect these changes in the slides deck as well (and vice versa, when user changes the title of the poll in the slides deck, data in our own DB gets updated).

Comment: Still confusing. Could you update your question with all of the code? I'm particularly interested in the trigger that makes add-on know that the web-app/poll has been inputted/modified.

Comment: @Tanaike, (1) we could make it less sophisticated and ignore these changes if they originated from the data itself (we would only update the slide when that particular user used the particular addon instance to change the poll's title). But this would only be like addressing a symptom not the main issue (the main issue being, two simultaneous requests result in a strange output like I described in the question). (2) Detect that another user is already updating the slide and reject the request (which we would need to handle gracefully in the frontend).

Comment: @TheMaster I updated the question, is the information enough?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to have asked about the detail of `There are other ways we could solve this but none of them is very elegant.`. From this, I thought that you have already have several solutions for achieving your goal. How about this?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I used the wrong words too :) I didn't mean that I know how to solve this concurrency issue (though maybe the option 2 would fall into this category) but maybe how to avoid the problem altogether (option 1). If it is hard to understand, I probably didn't illustrate the real-world use case well enough. Should I add more details to the question?

Comment: Option (3): We can use the Cache service to remember that a particular slide was just "synchronized" (updated) and prevent that from happening more than every 3 seconds.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I understood your replying. So from your question and replying, I proposed a workaround as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If this workaround was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Wow, that is a very elegant solution to the problem! :) I've marked it as the accepted answer, though I still need to check if the permissions and things like session are not going to be a problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- When 2 users are run your script for Google Slides, simultaneously, you want to run the script individually.

For this, how about this answer?

### Issue and workaround:

When I tested your situation, I could confirm the same issue like `My textMy text`. When I tested several times, in this case, I thought that the LockService might not affect to Google Slides. So as a workaround, I would like to propose to use Web Apps as the wrapper. Because it has already been known that Web Apps can run exclusively by the LockService. The flow of this workaround is as follows.

1. When the script is run, the script requests to Web Apps.
2. At Web Apps, your script is run.

By this, even when the script is run, simultaneously, the script can be exclusively run with the LockService.

### Usage:

The usage of this sample script is as follows. Please do the following flow.

#### 1. Prepare script.

When your script is used, it becomes as follows. Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor. Please set `MY_SLIDE_ID` and `MY_TEXTBOX_ID`.

```
function doGet() {

  // This is your script.
  var presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var textBox = presentation.getSlideById(MY_SLIDE_ID).getPageElementById(MY_TEXTBOX_ID);
  var text = textBox.asShape().getText();
  text.setText('My text');

  return ContentService.createTextOutput("ok");
}

// Please run this function.
function main() {
  var lock = LockService.getDocumentLock();
  if (lock.tryLock(10000)) {
    try {
      const url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec";  // Please set the URL of Web Apps after you set the Web Apps.
      const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
      console.log(res.getContentText())
    } catch(e) {
      throw new Error(e);
    } finally {
      lock.releaseLock();
    }
  }
}
```

#### 2. Deploy Web Apps.

1. On the script editor, Open a dialog box by "Publish" -> "Deploy as web app".
2. Select **"Me"** for **"Execute the app as:"**.

   - By this, the script is run as the owner.
3. Select **"Anyone, even anonymous"** for **"Who has access to the app:"**.

   - In this case, no access token is required to be request. I think that I recommend this setting for testing this workaround.
   - Of course, you can also use the access token. At that time, please set this to **"Anyone"**. And please include the scope of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` to the access token. These scopes are required to access to Web Apps.
4. Click "Deploy" button as new "Project version".
5. Automatically open a dialog box of "Authorization required".

   1. Click "Review Permissions".
   2. Select own account.
   3. Click "Advanced" at "This app isn't verified".
   4. Click "Go to ### project name ###(unsafe)"
   5. Click "Allow" button.
6. Click "OK".
7. Copy the URL of Web Apps. It's like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec`.

   - **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please redeploy as new version. By this, the modified script is reflected to Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
8. Please set the URL of `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec` to `url` of above script. And please redeploy Web Apps. By this, the latest script is reflected to the Web Apps. So please be careful this.

#### 4. Test this workaround.

Please run the function of `main()` by 2 users, simultaneously as you have tested. By this, it is found that the script is run exclusively. In my environment, in this case, I confirmed that even when the LockService is not used, the script is exclusively run. But I would like to recommend to use the LockService just in case.

### Note:

- This is a simple sample script for explaining this workaround. So when you use this, please modify it for your actual situation.
- About the situation that the LockService might not affect to Google Slides, in the current stage, although I'm not sure whether this is the bug, how about reporting this to [the Google issue tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker)? Unfortunately, I couldn't find this issue at the current Google issue tracker.

### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)